# Unity-2d: Why are two trigger colliders interacting?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I thought that trigger colliders were not meant to interact with each other, I have the following game object:
[image]

(The "AttackArea Game Object is a child of a "Player" Game Object)You can see I set it to be a trigger, the script "Attacks" only has the following code:

```
public int attackStrength;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.GetComponent<Health>() != null && collision.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        Debug.Log("touched: " + collision.name);
        Health health = collision.GetComponent<Health>();
        health.ReduceHealthPoints(attackStrength);
    }
}
```

The OnTriggerEnter2D method is getting called when this Polygon collider touches a Circle collider also set as a trigger:

[image]

Not sure why the two trigger colliders are interacting at all, I thought that wasn't possible.

These are the RigidBody settings on the game object that has the Polygon Collider 2D (it's parent):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the `isTrigger` property set to true, the collider will not collide, but it will send trigger events.

If you do not want to interact with certain game objects you can add tags to the relevant game objects and [compare the tags](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html).

For example:

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.CompareTag("CircleCollider")) return;
}
```